Serve modules from node_modules fail for import statement
I need guidance how to fix a problem for import statement in a JavaScript module execute in browser. When it import module it need to declare full script path to load it, I can fix this in my script.
Instead of using:
 import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
 import Adapter from 'chartjs-adapter-dayjs-4';


I use:
 import Chart from '/chart.js/auto/auto.js';
 import Adapter from '/chartjs-adapter-dayjs-4/dist/chartjs-adapter-dayjs-4.esm.js';

and this fixes it but sometimes module from npm calls other dependencies and I can't fix like
 import '@kurkle/color';

My web app is like:
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'node_modules')));
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));


What I'm expecting is Express to resolve module internal structure and resolve the module name, e.g. import Chart from 'chart.js/auto' will be resolved as 'chart.js/auto/auto.js'.
just forgot, using parcel all is working fine, but i want to use express because of ejs and i,m confort whit it.

Express.js alone simply does not do this. You can of course write your own middleware for it, but you're much better off using a dedicated library like parcel or vite.
